# ActionLists for Windows.Forms in runtime

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0, actionlist

I tried those sites

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/actionlist.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/CradsActions.aspx

to create actionlist, it work well if I use buttons in design time, but creating button in runtime I cannot assign action to it , I cannot do the same step in the image ,in code behind , I cannot find this property

[image]

any idea how to do that

Answer (score 0):

At runtime you need to use the following code,

`this.actionList1.SetAction(this.toolStripMenuItem1, this.actNew);`